# Spurious arguments to __new__ when using metaclass

Tags: python-3.x, new-operator, metaclass

I am trying to learn about metaclasses in python 3.7 and have the following code

```
class Foo(type):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)


class Bar(metaclass=Foo):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print(cls)
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


b = Bar()
```

When I run it I get the output

```
<class '__main__.Bar'>
(<class '__main__.Bar'>,)
{}
```

and the error

```
File "meta/main.py", line 91, in __new__
    return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: object.__new__() takes no arguments
```

where the line correpondse to the `__new__` call in `Bar`

I can't work out why the second `<class '__main__.Bar'>` is being passed in. If I change `Bar` to not use the `Foo` metaclass (i.e. change `class Bar(metaclass=Foo):` to `class Bar:`) I get

```
<class '__main__.Bar'> 
()
{}
```

and no errors (as I would expect). Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in an extra argument on calls:

```
def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

`__call__` is not an implicit static method, drop that `cls` argument:

```
def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```